# Replace \n with <br> tag on a model variable that I use $sce.trustAsHtml() on

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-filter

I use the combination of the 2 following filters to first strip all the HTML from the user input from obvious reasons(preventing attacks), and than replace all the \n in 
 tags.

```
<span data-ng-bind-html-unsafe="model.userInput | noHTML | newlines"></span>
```

---

```
  filters.filter('newlines', function () {
      return function(text) {
        console.log(text)
          return text.replace(/\n/g, '<br/>');
      }
  })
  filters.filter('noHTML', function () {
      return function(text) {
          return Boolean(text) ? text
                  .replace(/&/g, '&amp;')
                  .replace(/>/g, '&gt;')
                  .replace(/</g, '&lt;') : '';
      }
  });
```

the problem is that in angular 1.2.2 bind-html-unsafe is deprecated, and you must use $sce (strict contextual escaping) to 'trust the html', which returns a function, on which I obviously cannot apply those filters.

new code:

```
ctrls.controllers('someCtrl', function($scope, $sce){
$scope.trusterInput = $sce.trustAsHtml($scope.userInput);
});
```

---

Error:

`TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'replace'
    at Scope.<anonymous> (http://localhost:8000/js/filters.js:20:20)
    at fnInvoke (http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.2/angular.js:9756:21)
    at OPERATORS.| (http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.2/angular.js:9271:59)
    at extend.constant (http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.2/angular.js:9701:14)
    at OPERATORS.| (http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.2/angular.js:9271:74)
    at extend.constant (http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.2/angular.js:9701:14)
    at Object.getStringValue (http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.2/angular.js:16990:41)
    at Scope.$digest (http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.2/angular.js:11494:47)
    at Scope.$apply (http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.2/angular.js:11740:24)
    at http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.2/angular.js:13265:36`

Obviously becasue $sce returns a function and not a primitive(value of 'text'):
`TrustedValueHolderType {$$unwrapTrustedValue: function, $$unwrapTrustedValue: function, valueOf: function, toString: function, valueOf: function…}
$$unwrapTrustedValue: function () {
arguments: (...)
get arguments: function ThrowTypeError() { [native code] }
set arguments: function ThrowTypeError() { [native code] }
caller: (...)
get caller: function ThrowTypeError() { [native code] }
set caller: function ThrowTypeError() { [native code] }
length: 0
name: ""
prototype: Object
__proto__: function Empty() {}
<function scope>
__proto__: TrustedValueHolderType`

Any ide on how to solve this, beside calling my filters programmatically before the $sce, which is hardly the Angular way of doing things

Comment: If it doesn't enhance user experience in some way, escaping and removing HTML on the client side has no benefit, and certainly doesn't improve security, as that is something you do on the serverside.

Comment: We would do it normally, but, we also have mobile clients, which don't phrase HTML, thus the server plainly returns what it gets(minus special chars).
The idea is to replace new lines with <br> tags within angular, and to do it in the DOM context with $sce, not to achieve security

Comment: `/\n/g` is a poor way to match newlines.  You may end up with `\r<br>` on some platforms, which may copy/paste poorly.  Perhaps `/\r?\n/g`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used this function to allow saving an escaped html with only newlines enabled to a scope variable that will be used in the DOM context, obviously the user input ng-model, has to point to another variable, and then when saving, applying the changes or loading the text from the backend at the first place , I am calling this function again.

```
$scope.layout.allowSpaces = function(input){
    return $sce.trustAsHtml($filter('newlines')($filter('noHTML')(input)));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of writing your own HTML escaper, just let the auto-escaper do it for you, and instead of replacing newlines with `<br>` just use the CSS property `white-space: pre`.

```
TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'replace'
at Scope.<anonymous> (http://localhost:8000/js/filters.js:20:20)
```

occurs because `text` is not a string -- the contextual auto-escaper has already done the first step for you, and converted the string to a privileged SCE safe HTML value.

---

> ```
> $sce.trustAsHtml($scope.userInput)
> ```

is risky.  Echoing a naïve user's input back to them as HTML can be dangerous if they are being [socially engineered](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Social_engineering_%28security%29) to copy/paste text that really comes from an attacker.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, but I believe that you didn't get the point of it all, I don't want to trust all html, I just want to convert \n to <br> tags.
Please look at my answer below for what I used

Comment: @OlegTikhonov, maybe you didn't understand my suggestion about using `whitespace:pre`.  Do you want to convert newlines to `<br>` or do you want the newlines in the original to show up on the screen?  Why are the `<br>` elements necessary?  Is there some JavaScript which depends on those elements showing up in the DOM independent of their effect on line-breaking?

Comment: white-space: **pre-line**;    is better the **pre**, as it strips the white space and tabs (IE 8+)

Answer (score 2):

I ran into a similar problem when trying to test the return value of `$sce.trustAsHtml`. In my case I wanted to verify the string as part of a unit test.

I discovered that you can use [`$sce.getTrusted`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24sceDelegate#methods_gettrusted) which will return the value originally passed to `$sce.trustAsHtml`, in this case a string containing HTML, which you can then apply a filter to in the usual way.

Therefore the filter could look something like this:

```
.filter('noHTML', function ($sce) {
  return function(text) {
      text = $sce.getTrusted($sce.HTML, text); // this gets the original (unsafe) HTML as a string which can then be filtered
      var result =  Boolean(text) ? text
              .replace(/&/g, '&amp;')
              .replace(/>/g, '&gt;')
              .replace(/</g, '&lt;') : '';
      return $sce.trustAsHtml(result); // you need to do this again before returning otherwise you will get a 'Attempting to use an unsafe value in a safe context.' error
  }
});
```

See this fiddle I made demonstrating it: http://jsfiddle.net/GeTMJ/

In this way you can just apply the filter as usual and you don't have to worry about calling the filter programatically, which, as you say, is not such an 'Angular' way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using this to enable HTML content in ng-bind:

```
app.config(function ($sceProvider) {
    $sceProvider.enabled(false);
})
```

It completely disables SCE, so use it for demonstration purposes only!
Do not use in new projects.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Hasan, but disabling $sce is too much of a threat (xss etc..)

Comment: @OlegTikhonov i agree :)